# How to write the Xmlnode to new Xml

Tags: c#

i have an XML like

```
<Books>
<book>
<filename>QA Assurance </filename>
<author>john</author>
</book>
<book>
<filename>Dev CSharp</filename>
<author>pattersons</author>
</book>
</Books>
```

I need to read this XMl and i need to create a new with only filename="Dev CSharp" i want to copy the whole node book and create a new XML in C#

Regards
Dev

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("original.xml");
XElement book = doc.Descendants("book")
                   .Where(book => (string) book.Element("filename") == "Dev CSharp")
                   .Single();

XElement newDoc = new XElement("Books", book);
newDoc.Save("new.xml");
```